# Local Database from Text File

Tags: sql-server, database, winforms, sqlite

I have a SQL DB on cloud where I cannot run SQL queries due to permissions however i can download data using REST APIs so I plan to download 4-5 table using API which are exposed. Now there are SQL Queries which i want to run on this data as I do on a non-cloud machine i.e. local dev box.

I read about SQLLite however I am looking for much lighter options since I just need it for Select Queries with basic joins. Kindly suggest if I can use some other DB like Access, SQL lite etc. without installation and still ensure that it runs on all x86 machines. I will also be happy if there is a text based DB which allows running basic queries.

Example
    Select A.Col1, A.Col2, (A.Salary * B.Days) from Table A, Table B
    where A.some condition with B order by zzz group b zzz

I am looking for your guidance if I can some how download data from table A and B and put that in a local DB file which does not need installation and then run existing queries on it.

i.e.

```
<Table>
    <TableName>A</TableName>
    <DataRow>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Data for row 1 />
    </DataRow>
    <DataRow>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Data for row 1 />
    </DataRow>
</Table>
```

Comment: Looks like XML, whcih would only be accessable via SQLite if you first use an parser to fill an SQLite db on your machine. But if you do that, the XML parser might also do whatever data retrieval you plan; i.e. while doing the parsing, think out of the box. However, your queries look to me like SQL(ite) is the right tool. I think you are looking for a parser XML->SQLite.

Comment: I googled a little, many results talk about XML->SQLite, some even here on StackOverflow. But all I have seen are in the context of Android. But I understood your question to be about cloud service and home machine "PC". Would the Android discussions help you?

Comment: I got a way now. I will put the pre requisite for the tool to have connection to a SQL with write so first I will create tables populate them with data from Cloud and then run my queries on it. I have not explored SQL lite if it can be shipped with Tool Application and also managing space of it will be an overhead since people normally do not clean SQL lite DB (since its in local and over looked most of the time).

Comment: Sounds interesting. Would you like to create an answer yourself? It would give you much nicer formatting options than a comment. And if you polish a little you could end up with an interesting Q/A pair. That might attract some reputation for you.

Comment: yes.. I am new to this platform. will use comment for this from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got some of it today and seems I need to work on it for larger data. I first had a call to my webservice that the product exposes to share schema with details like int, varchar etc. I then fired a message to get list of object keys and then got them objects one by one. So in 2 steps, 
1. I could drop and create the table with new columns (if earlier user imported Task with only Property and Property2 and now trying to import Property1 and Property3). Also create an insert statement template for same with Column Names.
2. Get Data from server one by one and then create insert statements and execute on SQL DB

These webservices are product specific so I am happier now. Thanks for all your help and support here.